# How to run Flutter app on Mac or Web or any other specific Target?

Tags: android, ios, macos, flutter

Most of the time I turn on the emulator/simulator before I run the Flutter app from Android Studio.

I closed them all off and tried to run it in MacOS.

When I try to run it, it shows a dialog :

> ❌ "No connected device found, please connect a device......"

### but..

`flutter devices` **command** shows `macOS` as well.

How to run Flutter App in macOS?

Comment: I didn't have an idea of how to do this before. But after seeing your answer, it helped me. TIL. Thanks  @erluxman

Comment: heheh thanks. you can thumb up if you like :P

Comment: Hey @erluxman, how did you get the answer to your asked question so fast ? Just curious hehehe

Comment: I was writing the question, and a flash came in mind to run the command "flutte run"  and there was a help message in command line.  Then there is an option to answer my own question. As I had invested some time in writing question I invested some more to write the answer. As others may not get lucky like me :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always used to run apps from **"Run Menu or touchbar's ▶️ button** so I got that error  ❌.

If someone is like me and confused about this thing, here is the trick:

Use flutter command line tool and use `flutter run` with `-d` parameter

### Remember `-d` is very Important

```
❌flutter run macOs

✅flutter run -d  macOS
```

You can also run on Chrome like this:

```
✅flutter run -d  chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

### Run app into web

#### Flutter sdk version 2.0.1, channel stable

#### Also stable for web

Run flutter app on any browser(Recommended : Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge)

First open the terminal and create new flutter project

```
$ flutter create flutter_web_test
```

Go to project directory, run command then restart the ide

```
$ flutter config --enable-web
```

Then

```
$ flutter run -d web-server
```

a localhost url will be created like : http://localhost:33695. Copy the url and paste into browser.

If your sdk is not updated then run

```
$ flutter channel stable
$ flutter upgrade
```

If chrome browser is installed then try with the command.It will show the connected device

```
$ flutter devices
```

To run app into only chrome browser

```
$ flutter run -d chrome
```